# How to do an unattended install of Visual Studio 2008 Express on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, windows-installer, visual-studio-2008, unattended

I tried [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/03/24/how-to-silently-install-the-components-included-with-the-visual-studio-2008-express-editions/) but it did not work on Windows 7.

I would like to install Visual Studio 2008 from a batch file on Windows 7. We can assume I have the .iso file downloaded already.

Answer (score 0):

[Mount the iso](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/storage/mount-diskimage)

Find the installer and experiment with [different switches](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php).

If it's an MSI, try `/qn` or `/quiet` and it might need `/norestart`

InstallShield uses `/s` and if it calls more installers then try `/s /a /s` or `/s /v"/qn"` or some combination depending on how the installer is setup.